# How to add a File Provider to a MacOS Swift app?

Tags: swift, macos, fileprovider, fileprovider-extension

On iOS, there is the [File Provider API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider) to create "virtual folders" (folders where the content is provided by an app). How could I do something similar on MacOS? If you wonder why I would want to do this, it's just that I'm trying to understand how cloud storage apps work.

PS: Sorry for bad English, I'm French.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In macOS Big Sur there is a [NSFileProviderReplicatedExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/nsfileproviderreplicatedextension) protocol which should "Replicate" the iOS NSFileProviderExtension. 
The API appears to be working on macOS 11.3+ and Xcode 12.5 has brought back the required FileProvider Extension target. There is also a [workaround](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/122351?answerId=645095022#645095022) in Xcode 12.2 to add the target manually. 
During WWDC21 we also got some [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/macos_support/syncing_files_on_macos) from Apple, which should make the extension a bit easier to implement.

Comment: @Rivera Yes, I can confirm, that this extension launches on both M1 and Intel Macs, although some parts of the protocol are still marked as _Beta_. However, the core functionality should now work on all Macs running macOS 11.0 or later.

Comment: The lastest beta of Xcode, 12.5 beta 3 comes with an extension template for file providers (similar to finder sync extensions). This should save you some trial and error. Unfortuantely, I was unable to make it work properly. But this is probably due to my lack of knowledge in Xcode, Swift, etc....

Comment: That FruitBasket example by Apple is I think the most complicated example app ever released by Apple.

Answer (score 2):

Grab Xcode 12.5 beta 3 which includes the templates to create a macOS File Provider:

https://developer.apple.com/download/